# Remove S3 Object based on filename

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3

I'd like to remove all files containing key word 'update' from an S3 bucket. The following script will correctly read out the files containing 'update' but the `Remove-S3Object` command will delete the folder and all files in the folder, not just files containing 'update'.

```
Set-AWSCredentials -AccessKey $s3AccessKey -SecretKey $s3SecretKey

$s3Contents = (Get-S3Object -BucketName "$s3Bucket" -Key "path/test/" -AccessKey $s3AccessKey -SecretKey $s3SecretKey).Key
Write-Host 'Here are the contents' $s3Contents -ForegroundColor Green

foreach($x in $s3Contents){
    If($x -like '*Update*'){
            (Remove-S3Object -BucketName "$s3Bucket" -Key "$x" -AccessKey $s3AccessKey -SecretKey $s3SecretKey).key
    }
}
```

The full file paths are as follows:

```
Path/user/tier1/manual-retouch/test/File1.UPDATE.jpg
Path/user/tier1/manual-retouch/test/File2.Work.jpg
Path/user/tier1/manual-retouch/test/File3.jpg
```

If I add `-Whatif` to the `Remove-S3Object` I get the following return:

`What if: Performing the operation "Remove-S3Object (DeleteObjects)" on target "".`

However, without `-Whatif` the powershell script will prompt me with `Are you sure you want to perform this action? Performing the operation "Remove-S3Object (DeleteObjects)" on target "".` 4 times and will delete all there files and the folder.

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The Remove-S3Object command will delete the folder and all files in the folder not just files with update in the filename.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the names of files that were incorrectly deleted? Please edit your question to show the full Key of the object (including the path).

Comment: I have added some more detail @JohnRotenstein

Comment: Before the `Remove-S3Object` command, can you print the name of the object that is being deleted? That should help you determine whether the problem is with the `if`, or with something else.

Comment: John, I was able to get this to work, thanks for your help. I will test with a larger sample and make sure it works correctly. Thank you! @JohnRotenstein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Key` (filename) of an Amazon S3 object includes the full path.

Here is a sample of Keys:

```
foo.txt
foo-update.txt
invoices/bar.txt
invoices/bar-update.txt
to-be-updated/grok.txt
```

The final line shows an object inside a folder called `to-be-updated`. The reality is that the folder doesn't actually exist. Rather, the Key (filename) of the object is `to-be-updated/grok.txt`.

Thus, if your code deletes any object that has `update` in its Key, then it will delete all objects in the `to-be-updated/` folder.

Also, please note that folders do not exist. Therefore, when the last object is deleted from a 'folder', the folder will no longer appear. This is nothing to panic about. It will automatically reappear when an object is placed in that path again.

(If you created a folder in the S3 management console, it actually creates a zero-length object with the name of the folder. Your code would delete this object if it contains the word `update`, which is another reason why the folder would be deleted.)

Comment: Thanks for this information, John. It is very helpful. I have added some more detail per your request.